# NameError: uninitialized constant FileUtils

Tags: ruby

I tried to copy a file from my desktop to another folder with this code:

```
 FileUtils.cp('image.png', '/folder/image.png')
```

I got this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant FileUtils
Did you mean? FileTest
```

I am trying to work out why I got the error.

Comment: `require 'fileutils'` before

Comment: Have you succeeded in working it out?

Comment: @sawa yeah I did, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`FileUtils`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) must be explicitly `require`d:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.cp('image.png', '/folder/image.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that first and it came back as true - however when I attempt to move the file again it returns this: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - image.png`.

Comment: @SamJohnson: this error means there was no such file (in the working directory). Check that working directory was exactly what you expected. And that the file is actually there. I assume you're familiar with the concept of "working directory" or you'll be able to figure this out.

Comment: This refinement is completely out of the scope of the OP. The question was how to overcome `NameError` and the code above perfectly answers it.

Comment: @mudasobwa In my original question I explained that I was a beginner to Ruby, so I feel like it's perfectly reasonable to ask a follow up question as I had no idea whether or not the two were related.